# Symfony: How to render a template as a simple txt

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have to render a template of an action as a simple `.txt` file.

How can I do this? Is there a way other than using the `Response` object?

Using a `Response` object:

```
    $content = $this->get('templating')->render(
        'AppBundle:Company:accountBillingInvoice.txt.twig',
        [
            'invoice' => 'This is the invoice'
        ]
    );
    $response = new Response($content , 200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

Comment: Check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/27693540/1857533

Comment: No, this is not right as this response sets the header as `application/json` while I need headers set to `text/plain`. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in the answer I posted to there is example of how to do text and json responses. Read the examples and documentation you linked to and try to understand it instead of waiting for ready.

Comment: I were only asking for a simpler way, I know how to do this "manually" :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't see what's wrong with using the `Response` object - it's pretty simple!

If you want to render text responses from many controller actions and you don't want to repeat yourself a lot, you can define some service class that builds up the response for you, like:

```
class TextResponseRenderer
{
    /** @var EngineInterface */
    private $engine;

    // constructor...

    /**
     * @param string $template The name of the twig template to be rendered.
     * @param array $parameters The view parameters for the template.
     * @return Response The text response object with the content and headers set.
     */
    public function renderResponse(string $template, array $parameters): Response 
    {
        $content = $this->engine->render($template, $parameters);

        $textResponse = new Response($content , 200);
        $textResponse->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

        return $textResponse;
    }
}
```

Other option may be writing a listener for the `kernel.response` that modifies the response headers, but this might be over-complicating things. See more info [here](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-create-a-response-filter-and-set-extra-response-headers/).